# Initial Directory for os.walk()

Tags: python

I'm trying to use os.walk() to print out all the files in a directory and its subdirectories. This is what I wrote:

```
def usewalk():
   for root, dirname, filename in os.walk("/"):
       print filename
```

I don't know what I should use as the directory for os.walk(). That is, I'm not sure what I should include in the parentheses. I thought if I used "/", it would start from the directory that the file is in, but it printed out files that are not in it, such as "['.dbfseventsd', '.DS_Store', '.file', '.hotfiles.btree', 'mach_kernel']". It seems to me that it is starting from the default directory of Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `/` is the *root* of your filesystem. Use `.` to start in the **current** directory:

```
def usewalk():
   for root, dirname, filenames in os.walk("."):
       print filename
```

Print out `root` too to see the directory name being looped over; the following snippet prints full path names:

```
def usewalk():
   for root, dirname, filenames in os.walk("."):
       for filename in filenames:
           print os.path.join(root, filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

As correctly stated before me - the `/` directory is your systems root directory.

For a good starting point, you have several options:

1. Start from your current working directory: `os.walk(os.getcwd())`
2. Start from where your Python file is: `os.walk(os.path.dirname(__file__))`
3. Start from your users home directory: `os.walk(os.getenv('HOME'))`
4. Get the directory as an argument to your program/function.

I would not recommend starting from `.` since it might not be portable to windows (neither will the `getenv` option, but it's a good choice for a unix based program). Use `os.getcwd()` instead for portability and correctness.

I would recommend #4 - because it will yield the most useful and predictable code.

Answer (score 0):

`/`is the root directory. You're probably confusing it with `./` which is a common way to refer to the current directory.

Comment: Are . and ./ the same?

Comment: @user1691278: yes, just the same as addressing another directory with either `/path/to/directory` or `/path/to/directory/`.